# How to prevent a QMainWindow from being moved with moveEvent?

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

I would just like to be able to prevent my `QMainWindow` from being moved.
I saw that it was possible to reimplement the `moveEvent` function.

Here is what I tried:

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
void MainWindow::moveEvent(QMoveEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "move";
    event->ignore();
}
```

`mainwindow.h`

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTemporaryFile>
#include <QMoveEvent>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    void moveEvent(QMoveEvent *event);

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

My "moveEvent" function is called correctly, but I can still move the window, where am I wrong?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#moveEvent): `"When the widget receives this event, it is already at the new position"`.  So simply ignoring the event won't prevent the move.

Comment: Ok I also realized it in the meantime, but how do you think we can do to prevent it from being moved?

Comment: If the `QMainWindow` is a top level window then its properties re. moving, maximizing etc. are probably down to the window manager being used.  Can I ask you why you want to prevent it being moved?  It almost sounds like an xy-problem.